# DHCP Starvation Attack doesn't work in my virtual lab

Tags: dhcp, starvation

I've installed DHCP server in VirtualBox host-only network type. Other clients in VirtualBox can get their IP addresses successfully from my DHCP server.

I've decided to attack this DHCP server and want to consume all ip adresses that it can serve. But i was failed. I used dhcpstarv, pig.py, yersinia tool to achive my goal. But all tools sent many DHCP Discover packets instead DHCP request packets so that no consume happened in server.

Are these tools supposed to be sent DHCP request message? How can I do that?

Comment: yersinia should do the attack successfully

Comment: Can you share yersina pcap file or just output in this attack. It sends multiple DHCP DISCOVER Message, but not DHCP request Message. It should send request message? I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Yersinia sends the DISCOVERY packet to exhaust the ip pool. The request packet is sent only after an offer is sent by the server. Here is a picture about how it works:

[image: DHCP]

If you want more info about type of DHCP packets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Operation

It is suppossed after a Discovery packet is sent, the server response is an offer and then Yersinia should send the request packet but it will only request the packet if the offer is received.

- Possible troubleshooting and suggestions:

Try it on other different DHCP server to compare results.

Maybe there is a problem on your DHCP server.

It is supossed to be working. Maybe in other environment could be some kind of protection by the switch (Port Security, DHCP Snooping, Dynamic ARP inspection (DAI), etc). But you said you configured it on your NAT VirtualBox network so there is no protection at all.

Check your network settings, be pretty sure about you are well configured on the right network and check if everything is (virtually) connected as it is supposed to be.

Comment: The answer is good. I've configured my virtual lab in host-only network and configured Debian 9.0 as DHCP server in this network by installing isc-dhcp-server program. The other client virtual host get their ip from my debian dhcp server. There is no problem in there. I'll make some effort with yersinia.